# Paste a content with HTML tags to Contenteditable DIV

Tags: javascript, html, formatting, contenteditable, paste

I'll try to explain my problem)
I have a DIV element with content like:

```
<div contenteditable>
   <p>Some text</p>
   <p>Some text</p>
   <p><img src="myserver/path/image.jpg"></p>
   <p id="111">Some text</p>
   <p><img src="myserver/path/image.jpg"></p>
   <p>Some text</p>
</div>
```

And I want to paste some **outside html content** in the middle of this - for example - after id=111 parag.
This **outside html content** looks like:

```
   <p>Some text</p>
   <p><img src="OUTERSERVER/path/image.jpg"></p>
   <p>Some text</p>
   <p><img src="OUTERSERVER/path/image.jpg"></p>
   <p>Some text</p>
```

But this **outside html content** should be formatted automatically. Why?
Because I should change img src "OUTERSERVER/path" to "myserver/path" **for pasted content only**.

Im really tired with this problem. Can you help me please?)
I use javascript only.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: So when you paste, you do not want to paste the HTML markup, but display what the markup would look like if you pasted it into your site?

Comment: I've tried to scan DIV after pasting by getElementsByTagName('img'), but it takes all <img> from DIV, not only new one. So it's paths will be changed to - I don't want it.
So I'm thinking to make a sub DIV (inside new <p>, thats appear after you press Enter). And than scan this sub DIV for <img>. But I can't do it right or it's not possible..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with pure javascript. then it should be look like

```
function insertAfter(refer, external) {
   refer.parentNode.insertBefore(external, refer.nextSibling);
}
var external = document.getElementById('external');
var refer = document.getElementById('111');
insertAfter(refer, external);
```

please go through the link for more details of the html

[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/w03dgn3a/3/)

Comment: Sorry, but you don't understand me)
The content I'll paste from clipboard, not from any other places.
And I need to scan it after pasting.